# Check if message has 7 letters, then send to a channel

Tags: discord, discord.js

So I am making a fun bot for our server, but I want to see when people play games, they use 7 letter codes, and I want to be able to send the codes to a log channel so I can watch the games after.

The code looks like this: ZESPHSH

the channel id that it needs to send to is: 783009285709496371

If you know how to help with this any would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like,

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
 if (message.content.length == 7) {
  client.channels
   .get('783009285709496371')
   .send(`${message.author.id} Playing at code ${message.content}`);
 }
});
```

Comment: `message` is not a string, it's a `Message` instance. Do you mean `message.content`?

Comment: Oh yep, oops. Let me change it

Answer (score 0):

```js
// with msg as a Message
if (msg.content.length !== 7) return; // or: if (msg.content.length === 7) {
const logChannel = client.channels.cache.get('783009285709496371');
logChannel.send(`${msg.author.id} | Playing at code ${msg.content}`);
```

You could also use the following code, to make the message easier to read, however the user will be mentioned if they have access to the log channel.

```js
logChannel.send(`<@${msg.author.id}> | Playing at code ${msg.content}`);
```